# Plotting grouped data by date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot the counts of some pandas dataframe columns, grouped by date:

`by_date = data.groupby(data.index.day).count()`

[image: result]

The data are correct, but the the `data.index.day` I specified is no good for plotting purposes:

[image]

Is there a way of specifying that I want to group by Python Date objects, or am I doing this completely wrong?

Update: Dan Allan's `resample` suggestion worked, but now the the xticks are unreadable. Should I be extracting them separately?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this task is more easily accomplished using `resample`, not `group`. How about

```
data.resample('D', how='count')
```

Comment: That worked, now all I have to do is fix the xtick labelling.

Comment: Something is wrong with your index. Pandas beautifies xtick labels automatically. For example, ``Series(randn(217), pd.date_range('20130401', '20130410', freq='H')).resample('D', how='count').plot()`` looks nice to me.

Comment: The resampling operation creates a MultiIndex. Calling unstack(level=1) solved it. Thanks again!